# Running an application on the Windows host machine when using Remote-WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a compilation environment for GBA development configured on a WSL2 Ubuntu instance. This is then opened in VSCode with the Remote-WSL extension.

I have a series of tasks that build the ROM, as well as a configuration for a remote debugger. However, I'm having a few issues.

In order to debug, I need to run mGBA on the host Windows machine. I then have to remotely connect into it with the debugger.

```
        {
            "name": "Launch mGBA GDB Remote",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./pokefirered_debug.elf",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "arm-none-eabi-gdb",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "172.20.144.1:2345",
            //"targetArchitecture": "arm",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "mGBA_debug"
        }
    ]
```

```
            "label": "mGBA_debug",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "/mnt/d/Pokémon Hacking/Software/mgba/mGBA.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "pokefirered_debug.gba"
            ],
            "group": "test",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": ["Build FireRed Debug"],
            "presentation": {
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "close": true
            }
        }
```

This task successfully runs mGBA, but the debugger never starts since the `mGBA_debug` task never finishes.
This works perfectly if I get rid of `preLaunchTask` and just run the mGBA_debug task manually, but this feels rather inelegant.

I assumed isBackground would work, but it did not. I also tried adding `"&"` to the args, but if I did this mGBA didn't open on the host machine.

Is there any way I can get the `mGBA_debug` task to return complete without closing the application?
Is there a better way to run windows applications on the host machine than my horrible hacky method that for some reason seems to work?

Comment: Instead of running mGBA directly, either run `bash` with `-c "your command here"` and then you can use `&`, or run `cmd.exe` with `/c "your command here"` (with Windows paths then) and then use the [`start` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start). Maybe it's even easier to use a shell script or a Python/node/etc script.

Comment: `&` seems to be a valid arg that doesn't error, mGBA just doesn't load. Using `cmd` has a different issue, since it's being run from a network location, I get the `UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.` error. That has given me an idea for using powershell however...